# How do I write a Java WebSocket Servlet that can support implementations for either Tomcat or WebLogic

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, weblogic

I'm in the process of designing a new chat module for a large Java-based webapp that uses Tomcat by default, but supports WebLogic for one of our clients. I have been looking into using WebSocket for this purpose, but I have found that there appears to be no common interface for WebSocket servlets, such as is the case with `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet`.

So, considering that it looks like I may need to define a different servlet implementation for each servlet container I wish to use, how can I handle the case where I don't know 100% of the time which container I'm in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You follow the specifications. [Java EE 7 has websockets, which were defined in JSR-356](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/websocket.htm). [Tomcat implements the Java WebSocket 1.1 API defined by JSR-356](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html), and [so does WebLogic](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/NOTES/whatsnew.htm#NOTES379).

Key interface is [ServerEndpoint](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpoint.html):

```
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@ApplicationScoped
@ServerEndpoint("/actions")
public class DeviceWebSocketServer {

    @Inject
    private DeviceSessionHandler sessionHandler;

    @OnOpen
    public void open(Session session) {
    }

    ...
}
```

[Here's a tutorial by Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html) on how to do it (from where I quoted the example above).

There's also simple and cool websocket example in the Tomcat example apps (code links: [backend](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/trunk/webapps/examples/WEB-INF/classes/websocket/chat/ChatAnnotation.java), [frontend](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/trunk/webapps/examples/websocket/chat.xhtml)) that are installed by default if you install Tomcat.